# Series of novels about humans migrating to a new planet in cylindrical spaceship(s)

Tags: story-identification

I read a series of sci-fi novels a few years ago and cannot remember the names of the novels or the author.

Here are some of the specific plot elements:

One of the ships' main entertainments was a zero gravity sport played in the center of the cylinder.  The main protagonist is a former sports star turned detective.  I believe the story starts with a murder mystery.  The ships are traveling to what they believe is an uninhabited planet for colonization.  There is a sophisticated agricultural system.  Each citizen is implanted with a tracking and communication device while young.  A group of people refuses to receive this implant and lives in the nether regions of the spacecraft, cultivating fungi.  Eventually, in follow on novels, they reach the planet only to discover that is inhabited and some of the humans on the ships have known this for some time.

I think I read them sometime between 2014 and 2018. No idea when they might have been published. I think I remember spaceships on the covers but that doesn't narrow it down much in the science fiction genre.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: I think I read them sometime between 2014 and 2018.  No idea when they might have been published.  I think I remember spaceships on the covers.  But that doesn't narrow it down much in the science fiction genre.

Answer (score 3):

Kudos to the Multnomah County Library in Portland, Oregon.  One of their librarians found the answer for me.

The books are by Patrick S. Tomlinson.  There are three books in the series:
The Ark (2015)
Trident's Forge (2016)
Children of the Divide (2017)

Comment: Glad you found it. Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.